# Laravel Mix warning

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-elixir, laravel-mix

[Laravel Mix Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml2dJ.png)

after I add this line in components file,

```
<chat-message v-for="message in messages" :message="message"></chat-message>
```

`npm num watch` compiler say warning. 

but when I remove this line

```
v-for="message in messages" :message="message"
```

no warning given

what is the problem?.

Comment: Please show your full error log from terminal/console and your component.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml2dJ.png

Comment: No this is a notification toast. Open your CLI application where you ran your command and copy the error log from there and post it here.

Comment: no error in cli . But  I'm concerned about warning notification in every compile time.